# how to define and smooth a 3D cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I created a 3D matrix as cv::mat which contain on each axis (X, Y and Z) avalue from 0 to 255, as follow:

```
int sizes[] = { 100, 100, 100 };
Mat *matrix;
matrix = new Mat(3,sizes, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
            //some values are 255
            matrix->at<float>(i,j,k) = 0;
            // and some of them are 255 : (TODO) 

        }
```

And now I want smooth the whole 3D matrix, how I can do that with opencv lib?

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19168573/2065121) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9814187/2065121) and maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18020438/2065121)? Perhaps you can do so and then edit your question to make it specific where you're having trouble. It seems to me that a lot of this is already answered here.

Comment: the first example it works, thanks,

Comment: still having troubles with smoothing !

Comment: You should edit your anwer and give us more information/describe your problem better. You could for example provide a minimal example with your problem.

Comment: Hi Sebastian Schmitz, I update the question above, hope now it is clear :)

Comment: Is my answer acceptable to you? If so please tick it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `new Mat()` to initialize an OpenCV Mat. There is no need for this. You also run the risk of forgeting to free your Matrix once finished with it.

Simply use:

```
Mat matrix(3,sizes, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

As for creating a 3D Matrix you can find a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938681/3481173)

If you wish to filter the 3D Matrix with a Gaussian filter you will find a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836258/opencv-filter-on-multi-dimension-mat/27635398#27635398)